# Jquery datagrid group view using two fields

Tags: jquery

Having a easyui jquery datagrid. Need to group it based on product id and requestor. I am able to group using one field. Please let me know on how to achieve this.

I have given one group field like this.

```html
<table id="conf_grid" class="easyui-datagrid" 
 data-options="url:'jsp/generate.json',method:'get',
    view:groupview,groupField:'req',
    groupFormatter:function(value,rows){return value+' - '+rows.length+' requests ';}">
```

Please suggest, can another field be included here or if the underlying js needs to be changed, please throw some light there.

Comment: Please let me know why this has been downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easyui JQuery doesn't support this.

We can achieve this by modifying the 'onBeforeRender' function in datagrid-groupview.js or we can replicate the same view with the modifications.